# Shell scripting and Json

Tags: linux, bash, json

Basically, I have an openwrt router. I want it to run a shell script to connect to an API, using its MAC address as authentication and download a JSON file.

As the API is not yet built I have made a JSON file manually, and I want the script to read some values from the JSON and store them in separate variables.

I used curl to get the JSON file, now I need the script to read it, and store each value in a sperate variable.

All I’m seeing online is use jq (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) but the little router's memory is only 4MB remaining, the router does have jshn installed (https://github.com/m-labs/openwrt-milkymist/blob/master/package/jshn/example.txt). Any ideas on the way i should write the script?

```
{
  "mac": "8d:ff:86:7d:9c",
  "adblock": "off",
  "parental": "off",
  "vpn": "newyork1.ovpn",
  "vpnstatus": "off",
  "status": "active"
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you control the format of the settings file you download?

Comment: Yep! its a typed json at the moment, I'll be making an app output the api when the shell scripts are working :)

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Wait, you have been given a JSON parsing utility. So use it, why are you asking us?

Comment: I found the box had this after the question was posted, so thought I would get peoples opinion on whether to us the jshn or another method, and of course, any examples would be brilliant. I appreciate everyone's time, but if no one else wants to comment it can be closed/deleted

Answer (score 3):

Since you control the content of that JSON file, and since you need to process it with shell on a low-memory device, don't use JSON: output *shell syntax* and you can `source` it directly

```
mac="8d:ff:86:7d:9c"
adblock="off"
parental="off"
vpn="newyork1.ovpn"
vpnstatus="off"
status="active"
```

Then, after you be downloaded it to, say, `status.sh`

```
. ./status.sh
do_something_with "$status"
do_something_else_with "$vpn" "$vpnstatus"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Glenn, its a very clever way to approach it but I believe the API will only output JSON. Thanks

Comment: Why? As you said, the api is not built yet.

Comment: I'm not building it, I can specify the output contents but not the format. Thanks

Comment: Well, see if you can request the api respects the http request's Content-Type. If you request "application/json" it should send you JSON, and if you request "text/plain" it can sent you var=value text